# Is Radeon HD 6950 working with 11.10?

Tags: drivers, 11.10, radeon

I have tried to install the AMD Proprietary Driver by following this guide
http://wiki.cchtml.com/index.php/Ubuntu_Natty_Installation_Guide
but I guess I didn't succeed. In the standard Unity mode, the movement of the windows were really slow/laggy, but the 2D mode was working just fine.

Can anyone who succeed to use 11.10 with HD6950 help me? Which driver should I use and how should I install it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use HD 5850, so it's not exactly the same, but my impression is that it's the same for all the newer cards. The proprietary driver is *much* slower than the open Radeon driver. I also had some problems with it, but none with the open driver. It's installed by default, so you don't need to install it. Your link doesn't appear to be functional, so I don't know what you did.

Comment: I made a fresh Ubuntu install and now everything seems to be perfect. The window movement is smooth also the videos. But sometimes I get some "rainbowish" areas on the screen. Is there any fix for them?

Comment: I haven't seen anything that would fit that description. Are they still there if you restart compiz? You can do that by pressing alt+f2 and running 'compiz --replace'. It'd be very nice to hear an answer to that, so when you have an opportunity, please try it and respond :)

Comment: Restarting the compiz fixed the issues with the Unity elements. But the same problem appears for example in Firefox too. If I restart it too then the problem gets fixed but it's annoying to restart every time it happens. 

Here is an example: http://img190.imageshack.us/img190/1869/l4e8c02bb7.jpg

This can happen anywhere. Like window borders, buttons, icons, etc.

Comment: Your card is overheating! Careful not to burn it, use vesa or something so it doesn't heat up for now. Try disabling compiz (no effects) asap and check if the temps go down.

Answer (score 1):

You should use the recommended auto installable stable secure drivers that Ubuntu supplies. It works on my 6870, will work the same on yours, just perfect.

You will get nothing extra by downloading and installing the drivers from ATI yourself.

Comment: You mean this ATI/AMD proprietary FGLRX graphics driver from the Additional Drivers program, or just use the default driver which comes with the Ubuntu?